# Connect to 2 networks simultaneously?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, dsl

I have here 2 wireless networks with a linksys wrtg54 access points. Each network has its own dsl line.

Is it possible to connect to the networks simultaneously?

I want to be able to access all the computers on network1 (192.168.1.1) and network2 (192.168.2.1)

Do I need 2 WLAN network cards in my computer? (Windows 7)
Is it also possible to use the 2 dsl lines in the same time for example to speed up some big file downloads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will require either 2 WiFi interfaces (a WiFi interface can only bind to 1 network at a time) or one WiFi and one Ethernet (if you don't mind using a wire).

You can easily add an extra WiFi interface to your computer using a cheap USB adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that only one network card can connect to a single network at a time. What you can do is use a wireless connection for one network and a wired connection for the other.